# How do I use gmail api in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, gmail-api

I'm using gmail api on my site with asp.net but I chose web client when getting credential but I get error

I use GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync but

> "Error: redirect_uri_mismatch" I get an error.

How do i use.

```
UserCredential credential; try{

        using (var stream = new FileStream(json, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                new[] { GmailService.Scope.GmailReadonly, GmailService.Scope.MailGoogleCom, GmailService.Scope.GmailModify },
                v1,
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(uygulamaAdi)
                );
        }
        var gmailService = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = uygulamaAdi
        });
        return gmailService;
    }
```

Comment: You need to create a [MCVE]. Don't just describe your code, show your code.

Answer (score 0):

#### Web applications (ASP.NET MVC)

When you use ASP.NET you need to set the redirect URI to your site in the [Google API Console](https://console.developers.google.com), that's the reason why you're getting  `Error: redirect_uri_mismatch"`. [Here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-asp.net-mvc) you can see a nice explanation on how to configure properly your credentials for this case.

#### ServiceAccountCredential

I think you were trying to do it more in [this way](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#serviceaccountcredential), which works for another type of implementation.